# SQL Server, SCSU and how to figure when string not compressed?

Tags: sql-server, unicode

SQL Server 2008+ using [SCSU](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr6/) compression for Page and Row compression as described in [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ee240835(v=sql.105)) and [blogs.msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2009/08/16/unicode-compression-in-sql-server-2008r2/)
But it is unclear how to figure is string compressed in database or not. For example NChar(20) field contains compressed value for

```
German "Öl fließt": D66C20666C6965DF74
Russian "Москва": 129CBEC1BAB2B0
```

and uncompressed for

```
Japanese "　♪リンゴ可愛いや可愛いやリンゴ。半": 00306A26EA30F330B430EF531B6144308430EF531B6144308430EA30F330B43002304A53
Korean "향찰/鄕札 구결/口訣 이두/吏讀": A5D530CC2F0015912D6720006CADB0AC2F00E353238A200074C750B42F000F545AF9
```

I was looking for any sign to figure is value compressed or not, but can't find any. SCSU implementations fails and there is nothing there to recognize uncompressed Unicode. How to figure is it SCSU compressed or pure Unicode inside?

Comment: Compression is transparent. Applications *never* see the compressed values. Wherever those binary values came from, it wasn't from SQL Server's compression.

Comment: Where did those binary values come from? How where they enterd and how were they retrieved? Can you post the table creation schema and code that inserts those values?

Comment: The articles you linked to say nothing about compressed contents being visible to applications. Without any information, this question will have to be closed

Comment: Of course values from mdf. And purpose is to get those values from there.

Comment: You can't just read values from the raw mdf file. Explain what you actually want to do in the question. This isn't a question about reading data from a database, this is about the file format of an `mdf` file. Something only Microsoft and authors of database recovery or backup tools should care about.

Comment: Why I can't if I can, ApexSQL can, SQL Server can and other special applications too.

Comment: The only built-in way to view and interpret the compressed data is by using the undocumented (but exceedingly well known) `DBCC PAGE` command to directly inspect the on-disk format of the page. [Here's an article by someone who did that](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/how-sql-server-data-compression/). Reverse engineering the bytes as they are on disk has to be left as a nontrivial exercise to the reader. Compression is an attribute of the columns and pages (stored in page and row headers), not directly of the contents.

Comment: Yes, special applications, whose authors have special knowledge: the binary layout of the mdf file. That's documented in SQL Server's Books online anyway. You ask about the file format in your question though, although *that's* what you're asking

Comment: I'm not asking about file format. Yes, some information documented in Microsoft blogs and books like "SQL Server internals". It is particular issue with NChar and NVarchar values that can be found in both mdf, ldf and raw data of DBCC and fn_dblog when Row or Page compression is used when text on korean or japanese.

Comment: Even if some kind MS engineer popped up and told you, these details are subject to change without notice between versions. The honorable way to find out is by doing the reverse engineering yourself (make pages with and without compressed strings, diff all the bits you see). This way, you're also equipped to deal with breakage if the scheme ever changes. Note that none of the internal tools for displaying data promise to do or not do anything with compression; the assumption that they display the relevant bits (instead of an incomplete or misleading summary) need not hold.

Comment: Because Japanese is documented to be compressed as well, I'd hazard a guess that the values you're seeing are actually conveniently decompressed already, to be shown either in `CHAR` or `NCHAR` format regardless of the column's type. If that is indeed the case, you'll have to dig deeper. Otherwise, there should a bit on the page somewhere that tells you what's what, as the bytes themselves are not distinguishing enough.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and of course 80% is reverse engineering because documentations provided some basic knowledge. And I did yet another database and analyzed every byte in rows - there is no space for flag describing is nchar string SCSU compressed or not (only ordinal row compression, short and long data sections, lengths), I was hoping to find some bit like for pointers in lengths - but everything there identical for compressed and not compressed.

Comment: Then SQL Server may be applying some simple but undocumented heuristic like "skip compression for short strings that aren't completely composed of BMP characters", but it's hard to see how the decompressor would detect that if not with a separate bit. You could try generating a lot of strings of different length and compositions to see if there's a tipping point of some sort. Alternatively, if you're really feeling adventurous, try finding the code in SQL Server that handles the compression -- symbols are available for many (not all) versions on the MS symbol servers.

Comment: Data from short test database, it based on ApexSQLLogDEMO (table TestAllTypes_RowCompression) test from ApexSQL, it can be downloaded for free at their page. I was wondering before why they testing that exact issue before I got same problem in my application. This is exact strings and values from several inserts, they both the same in log and mdf - everything is SCSU compressed except Korean and Japanese strings. SSMS shows them properly so yes, SQL Server engine know the difference and I hope it is not try-catch based or by analyzing asian codepages.

Comment: Since all I need is decompression it is exact problem how to detect. I see 30-th asian Unicode codepages etc, they can check high byte and first byte is it SCSU command sequence. And probably I should test same strings with Latin character as first byte or more.

Comment: Another thought: although it's not documented anywhere, the collation of a field may play a role. In Unicode types, the collation does not normally dictate how characters are stored, but I can well imagine it being allowed to play a role when compression is thrown in the mix. This is pure speculation, by the way, but at least something that also has to be tested, lest things fail when someone actually uses a JP or BIN collation.

Comment: Collation set to column and stored in syscolpars system table per rowset column. In case of test table it is Cyrillic_General_CI_AS, far from asian. There is no way to set different collation for one column in one row. Probably it is not related. I tried to add latin characters at the start and end like 'b향찰/鄕札 구결/口訣 이두/吏讀d' and it also stored uncompressed as "6200A5D530CC2F0015912D6720006CADB0AC2F00E353238A200074C750B42F000F545AF96400" where 'b' is 0062 and 'd' is 0064.

Comment: Also when I added 2 latin characters at the start and end to japanese string 'A　♪リンゴ可愛いや可愛いやリンゴ。半C', N'A　♪リンゴ可愛いや可愛いやリンゴ。半C' value became partially compressed "4108000E266A16CAD3940E53EF0E611B068406C40E53EF0E611B068406C4CAD39408020E534A43" vs "00306A26EA30F330B430EF531B6144308430EF531B6144308430EA30F330B43002304A53" (pure Unicode) before without 'A' and 'C'. There is some undocumented algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple: if count of bytes in array odd - it is compressed, if even - Unicode. If compressed but amount of bytes even then server adds meaningless byte at the end like SCSU tag that do nothing.